# Append an INSERT into SQL by a loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to generate an "insert into" SQL by a loop.

```
$orderrecord='INSERT into counter SET';

for ($rank=0; $rank<10; $rank++)
  { if (array_search($names[$rank],_$POST['v'])!==FALSE) 
    { $orderrecord.=" $names[$rank]=1, "; } ;}
```

The problem is, there will always be 1 extra comma that render the SQL syntax invalid. 
"INSERT into counter SET A=1, B=1, C=1," or "INSERT into counter SET , A=1, B=1, C=1". How to tackle this?

Comment: if $rank = 0, then don't put a comma before.  That's one way.

Comment: $rank[0] may not be appended. It is appended only if it exists in the array. So the first one appended may be [1] or [2] etc, or none at all.

Comment: `implode(',', array_filter($names, function($i) use(_$POST['v']) { return array_search($i, _$POST['v'])!==FALSE; } ));`

Comment: `rtrim` would remove the last instance of a specific character. You also might be open to SQL injections with this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$orderrecord = 'INSERT into counter SET';

for ($rank=0; $rank<10; $rank++) {
   if (array_search($names[$rank], $POST['v']) !== FALSE) {
      $orderrecord.=" $names[$rank]=1, ";
   }
}

$orderrecord = substr($orderrecord, 0, strlen($orderrecord) - 2);
```